# Yii2 - configure google cloud messaging

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I would like to configure GCM in my yii2 application. Any working packages that are available ?

I tried

```
bryglen/yii2-apns-gcm
```

which doesn't install due to composer errors. *(duccio/apns-php not found)*

Is there any basic template through which I can configure it easily?

Answer (score 0):

All should work properly. Just add

```
...
"bryglen/yii2-apns-gcm": "dev-master",
...
```

into your composer.json and type

```
composer update
```